# Binary polynomial Multiplication and division over 8 bit μc

Tags: c, assembly

I want to multiply and divide binary polynomials over a Galois Field of size (2^128) (multi precision multiplication and extended euclidean algorithm). 
Moreover, I want to use the previous algorithms on an 8-bit microcontroller (ATMega128).
Where can I find relevant libraries in C or Assembly ?
Ι d prefer C, if the implementation is not too inefficient.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What processor?  Assembly is processor-specific (well, at least more processor-specific) than C.

Comment: Yes, Scott Hunter you re right. It is ATMega128. I updated the question.

Comment: don't for get to carry the 01 ... surely there must be dozens of examples of this on the interwebs the arduino folks dont tend to keep to themselves...